# Git diff file by file instead of all at once

Tags: git

I've see someone do it before where they `git diff` and add an option so they see each file one at a time in their terminal instead of them all being listed out all at once. What is the option for this?

Comment: `git diff <filename>`

Comment: `git difftool`?

Comment: I suggest same as @SaugatAcharya

Comment: There was a way to see each file one by one without having to type each name. So it will show you the diff and then you press 'y' and it will show you the next file and so on